# SwiftUI/Combine - Subscribing to the latest value of a single Publisher

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm playing around a tad with Combine and SwiftUI for a little pet project of mine, learning as I go.

Here's the `LoginModel` at it current state:

```
public class LoginModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var domain: String = ""
    @Published var email: String = ""
    @Published var password: String = ""
    @Published var isValid: Bool = false
    public var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var credentialsValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        Publishers.CombineLatest($email, $password)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map { (email, password) in
                let emailValid = String.emailValid(emailString: email) // String extension function
                let passwordValid = password.count > 5
                return emailValid && passwordValid
        }
        .breakpointOnError()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    init() {
        // This works just fine
        _ = credentialsValidPublisher.sink { isValid in
            self.isValid = isValid
        }

        // However this does not work at all
        _ = domain
            .publisher
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { value in
                print(value)
        }
    }
}
```

Now from my current understanding is that a `@Published var foo: String` already has a `Publisher` attached to it. And that one should be able to use this directly to subscribe to its changes.

Changing `credentialsValidPublisher` variable over to this works too:

```
var credentialsValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
    Publishers.CombineLatest3($domain, $email, $password)
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .map { (domain, email, password) in
            let domainValid = URL.isValidURL(urlString: domain)
            let emailValid = String.emailValid(emailString: email)
            let passwordValid = password.count > 5
            return domainValid && emailValid && passwordValid
    }
    .breakpointOnError()
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

But this is not what I want. In my case I need a special `Publisher` in order to map a valid URL string over to a network request and then ping the server at hand to see if the provided server is responding.

Also this model is then connected to a SwiftUI view with a bunch of SwiftUI TextFields.
Any help to point me in the right direction will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I figure out the way to do it.
In the `LoginModel` underneath `var credentialsValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>` I added:

```
var domainValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
    $domain
        .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        .removeDuplicates()
        .map { domain in
            URL.isValidURL(urlString: domain)
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Then I can just subscribe to it in `init`.
I also added `AnyCancellable` properties that we call `.cancel()` on `deinit`.
Here's what the updated model looks like:

```
public class LoginModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var domain: String = ""
    @Published var email: String = ""
    @Published var password: String = ""
    @Published var isValid: Bool = false
    public var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    private var credentialsValidPublisherCancellable: AnyCancellable!
    private var domainValidCancellable: AnyCancellable!

    var credentialsValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        Publishers.CombineLatest3($domain, $email, $password)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .map { (domain, email, password) in
                let domainValid = URL.isValidURL(urlString: domain)
                let emailValid = String.emailValid(emailString: email)
                let passwordValid = password.count > 5
                return domainValid && emailValid && passwordValid
        }
        .breakpointOnError()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    var domainValidPublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        $domain
            .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .removeDuplicates()
            .map { domain in
                URL.isValidURL(urlString: domain)
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    init() {
        credentialsValidPublisherCancellable = credentialsValidPublisher.sink { isValid in
            self.isValid = isValid
        }

        domainValidCancellable = domainValidPublisher.sink { isValid in
            print("isValid: \(isValid)")
        }
    }

    deinit {
        credentialsValidPublisherCancellable.cancel()
        domainValidCancellable.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: I got error `Value of type 'AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>' has no member 'cancel'`